# How to set json data to footer list react

Tags: reactjs

I start working with react and i need to set mock json data to list in footer.

How i can set list dynamically to each module. I have 3 modules Company, Catalog, Contacts, and JSON:

```
const FOOTER_DATA = {
  menu: {
    title: "Company",
    items: [
      {
        title: "Link 1",
        link: "#",
      },
      {
        title: "Link 2",
        link: "#",
      }
    ],
  },
  catalog: {
    title: "Catalog",
    items: [
      {
        title: "Link Link 1",
        link: "#",
      },
      {
        title: "LinkLink 2",
        link: "#",
      },
      {
        title: "LinkLink 3",
        link: "#",
      },
      {
        title: "LinkLink 4",
        link: "#",
      },
      {
        title: "LinkLink 5",
        link: "#",
      },
      {
        title: "LinkLink 6",
        link: "#",
      }
    ],
  },
  contact: {
    email: "some-mail@gmail.com",
    tel: "777 777 777",
    work_time: {
      weekdays: "09:00 - 18:00",
      weekends: "10:00 - 16:00",
    },
  },
};
```

How i can set this for each jsx file, to special tags:

```
<Company />
      <Categories />
      <Contacts />
```

I am really beginner in react an i stuck in such issues.

Comment: can you please paste the whole code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the data as a prop to each element and render the data inside each component.

```
      <Company data={FOOTER_DATA?.menu}/>
      <Categories data={FOOTER_DATA?.catalog}/>
      <Contacts data={FOOTER_DATA?.contact}/>
```

For example you may have a JSX component for `Company` like below,

```
import React from "react";

const Company = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h2>{data.title}</h2>

            {data.items.map((item, index) => (
                <a key={index} href={item.link}>
                    {item.title}
                </a>
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
export default Company;
```